# Verify email reception by program in C++/Linux

Tags: c++, linux, smtp, libcurl, mailx

I have written a C++ server that send across mails over SMTP protocol asynchronously.
Now for the sake of testing I want to write some program/script that will help testers to verify if email is successfully received or not.

I looked for "mailx" utility, but could not figure out how to use it in shell script.

Is there any library that C++ provides or utility that linux has to verify email being received and check its contents?

Comment: Better use another smtp agent, like **qmail** or **sendmail**.  To do an exhaustive test of validation of SMTP requires more than a script.